# Value assigned inside init doesnt maintain the value

Tags: go

I'm working on Golang and am a little confused about how the `func init()` works. Lets's say that I have 2 packages called `main` and `pkg2`
inside main I am trying to call a variable that is inside pkg2 but its giving me nil. Basically this is the structure:

**Main Package:**

```
import (
    ...
    "github.com/myproject/config/pkg2"
)

func main () {
    if pkg2.Myvariable == nil {
      //it's nil. And it's entering in this conditional don't know why
    }
}
```

**PKG2 Package:**

```
package pkg2

import (
     ...some imports...
)

var MyVariable

func init () {
     MyVariable :=  "something"
     //Here I assign a value to MyVariable
     //I set an if here to check if it's executed
     //and MyVariable get a value correctly
}
```

I also noticed that the `init function` is executed before I even call `pkg2.Myvariable`. So, briefly: inside main package it's given nil, but inside init the value is assigned correctly, why then it return to nil?
What Am I missing? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you should change `:=` to `=`, because that way you are introducing a new var.

Comment: Yup. Looks like it's creating a local copy scoped to the init function instead of being available at the package level.